# Getting a WxPython panel item to expand

Tags: python, wxpython, frame, sizer

I have a WxPython frame containing a single item, such as:

```
class Panel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.text = wx.StaticText(self, label='Panel 1')
```

I have a frame containing several panels, including this one, and dimensions are ruled by sizers.
I would like this `StaticText` to expand.
Using a `BoxSizer` containing just the text and setting the `wx.EXPAND` flag does the trick, but it seems silly to use a sizer just for one item.

Any simpler solution?

(I could just add the `StaticText` to the parent frame's sizer directly, but for my design it makes more sense to start with a frame directly.)

---

I just realized that when creating a `BoxSizer` with one item doesn't work with `wx.VERTICAL`:

```
class Panel1(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.BackgroundColour = 'red'
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.Sizer = sizer
        self.list = wx.ListBox(self, choices=[str(i) for i in xrange(100)])
        sizer.Add(self.list, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Fit(self)
```

Of course it's ok with one item, but what if I want to add an item vertically later and still make both of them expand (e.g. when the user's window is expanded)?

**Edit:** ah, I just found out that proportion must be used in order to make boxsizers grow in both ways. (i.e., replace 0 with 1 in `BoxSizer.Add`'s call.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `wx.Frame` will automatically do this if it only has one child.  However, a `wx.Panel` will not do this automatically.  You're stuck using a sizer.  If you find yourself doing it a lot, just make a convenience function:

```
def expanded(widget, padding=0):
    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    sizer.Add(widget, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, padding)
    return sizer

class Panel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.text = wx.StaticText(self, label='Panel 1')
        self.SetSizer(expanded(self.text))
```

I threw the padding attribute in there as an extra bonus. Feel free to use it or ditch it.

Comment: Yep, proportion makes it grow in the sizer's direction.  wx.EXPAND makes it expand to fill the other direction.  Use them both to grow in both directions.