# How to understand wxGridBagSizer?

Tags: python, wxpython

I was trying to design gui for my app using wxPython. 
I was using wx.GridBagSizer, but I encountered a few problems with it.

[image]

First layout is what I get from my code and the second one is the layout I would like to get. I think I don't understand pos and span attributes correctly. I would be grateful for any explanation. Below is my current code:

```
class MyFrame1 ( wx.Frame ):

def __init__( self, parent ):
    wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 561,401 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

    self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

    gbSizer1 = wx.GridBagSizer( 0, 0 )
    gbSizer1.SetFlexibleDirection( wx.BOTH )
    gbSizer1.SetNonFlexibleGrowMode( wx.FLEX_GROWMODE_SPECIFIED )

    gbSizer1.SetMinSize( wx.Size( 0,0 ) ) 
    self.m_panel25 = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 10,10 ), wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
    self.m_panel25.SetBackgroundColour( wx.SystemSettings.GetColour( wx.SYS_COLOUR_WINDOWTEXT ) )

    gbSizer1.Add( self.m_panel25, wx.GBPosition( 0, 0 ), wx.GBSpan( 1, 3 ), wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )

    self.m_panel41 = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
    gbSizer1.Add( self.m_panel41, wx.GBPosition( 5, 0 ), wx.GBSpan( 1, 1 ), wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )

    self.m_panel26 = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 10,10 ), wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
    self.m_panel26.SetBackgroundColour( wx.SystemSettings.GetColour( wx.SYS_COLOUR_INFOBK ) )

    gbSizer1.Add( self.m_panel26, wx.GBPosition( 0, 3 ), wx.GBSpan( 1, 1 ), wx.ALL, 5 )

    self.m_panel28 = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 10,10 ), wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
    self.m_panel28.SetBackgroundColour( wx.SystemSettings.GetColour( wx.SYS_COLOUR_INFOBK ) )

    gbSizer1.Add( self.m_panel28, wx.GBPosition( 0, 4 ), wx.GBSpan( 1, 1 ), wx.ALL, 5 )

    self.m_panel27 = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 10,10 ), wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
    self.m_panel27.SetBackgroundColour( wx.SystemSettings.GetColour( wx.SYS_COLOUR_INFOBK ) )

    gbSizer1.Add( self.m_panel27, wx.GBPosition( 0, 5 ), wx.GBSpan( 1, 1 ), wx.ALL, 5 )

    self.m_panel29 = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 10,10 ), wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
    self.m_panel29.SetBackgroundColour( wx.SystemSettings.GetColour( wx.SYS_COLOUR_INFOBK ) )

    gbSizer1.Add( self.m_panel29, wx.GBPosition( 0, 6 ), wx.GBSpan( 1, 3 ), wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )

    self.m_panel30 = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 10,10 ), wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
    self.m_panel30.SetBackgroundColour( wx.SystemSettings.GetColour( wx.SYS_COLOUR_INFOTEXT ) )

    gbSizer1.Add( self.m_panel30, wx.GBPosition( 1, 3 ), wx.GBSpan( 5, 6 ), wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )

    self.m_panel31 = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 10,10 ), wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
    self.m_panel31.SetBackgroundColour( wx.SystemSettings.GetColour( wx.SYS_COLOUR_HIGHLIGHT ) )

    gbSizer1.Add( self.m_panel31, wx.GBPosition( 1, 0 ), wx.GBSpan( 1, 3 ), wx.ALL, 5 )

    self.m_panel32 = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 10,10 ), wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
    self.m_panel32.SetBackgroundColour( wx.SystemSettings.GetColour( wx.SYS_COLOUR_HIGHLIGHT ) )

    gbSizer1.Add( self.m_panel32, wx.GBPosition( 2, 0 ), wx.GBSpan( 1, 3 ), wx.ALL, 5 )

    self.m_panel39 = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 10,10 ), wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
    self.m_panel39.SetBackgroundColour( wx.SystemSettings.GetColour( wx.SYS_COLOUR_HIGHLIGHT ) )

    gbSizer1.Add( self.m_panel39, wx.GBPosition( 3, 0 ), wx.GBSpan( 1, 3 ), wx.ALL, 5 )

    self.m_panel40 = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 10,10 ), wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
    self.m_panel40.SetBackgroundColour( wx.SystemSettings.GetColour( wx.SYS_COLOUR_HIGHLIGHT ) )

    gbSizer1.Add( self.m_panel40, wx.GBPosition( 4, 0 ), wx.GBSpan( 1, 3 ), wx.ALL, 5 )


    self.SetSizer( gbSizer1 )
    self.Layout()

    self.Centre( wx.BOTH )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are really close. Take note of the changes made. What about this:

```
import wx

class MyFrame1 ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 561,401 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

        gbSizer1 = wx.GridBagSizer( 0, 0 )
        gbSizer1.SetFlexibleDirection( wx.BOTH )
        gbSizer1.SetNonFlexibleGrowMode( wx.FLEX_GROWMODE_SPECIFIED )

        gbSizer1.SetMinSize( wx.Size( 0,0 ) )
        self.m_panel25 = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 40,10 ), wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        self.m_panel25.SetBackgroundColour( wx.SystemSettings.GetColour( wx.SYS_COLOUR_WINDOWTEXT ) )

        gbSizer1.Add( self.m_panel25, wx.GBPosition( 0, 0 ), wx.GBSpan( 1, 3 ), wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_panel41 = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        gbSizer1.Add( self.m_panel41, wx.GBPosition( 5, 0 ), wx.GBSpan( 1, 1 ), wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_panel26 = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 10,10 ), wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        self.m_panel26.SetBackgroundColour( wx.SystemSettings.GetColour( wx.SYS_COLOUR_INFOBK ) )

        gbSizer1.Add( self.m_panel26, wx.GBPosition( 0, 3 ), wx.GBSpan( 1, 1 ), wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_panel28 = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 10,10 ), wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        self.m_panel28.SetBackgroundColour( wx.SystemSettings.GetColour( wx.SYS_COLOUR_INFOBK ) )

        gbSizer1.Add( self.m_panel28, wx.GBPosition( 0, 4 ), wx.GBSpan( 1, 1 ), wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_panel27 = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 10,10 ), wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        self.m_panel27.SetBackgroundColour( wx.SystemSettings.GetColour( wx.SYS_COLOUR_INFOBK ) )

        gbSizer1.Add( self.m_panel27, wx.GBPosition( 0, 5 ), wx.GBSpan( 1, 1 ), wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_panel29 = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 40,10 ), wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        self.m_panel29.SetBackgroundColour( wx.SystemSettings.GetColour( wx.SYS_COLOUR_INFOBK ) )

        gbSizer1.Add( self.m_panel29, wx.GBPosition( 0, 6 ), wx.GBSpan( 1, 3 ), wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_panel40 = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 40,10 ), wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        self.m_panel40.SetBackgroundColour( wx.SystemSettings.GetColour( wx.SYS_COLOUR_INFOTEXT ) )

        gbSizer1.Add( self.m_panel40, wx.GBPosition( 1, 3 ), wx.GBSpan( 5, 6 ), wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_panel31 = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 40,10 ), wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        self.m_panel31.SetBackgroundColour( wx.SystemSettings.GetColour( wx.SYS_COLOUR_HIGHLIGHT ) )

        gbSizer1.Add( self.m_panel31, wx.GBPosition( 1, 0 ), wx.GBSpan( 1, 3 ), wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_panel32 = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 40,10 ), wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        self.m_panel32.SetBackgroundColour( wx.SystemSettings.GetColour( wx.SYS_COLOUR_HIGHLIGHT ) )

        gbSizer1.Add( self.m_panel32, wx.GBPosition( 2, 0 ), wx.GBSpan( 1, 3 ), wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_panel39 = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 40,10 ), wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        self.m_panel39.SetBackgroundColour( wx.SystemSettings.GetColour( wx.SYS_COLOUR_HIGHLIGHT ) )

        gbSizer1.Add( self.m_panel39, wx.GBPosition( 3, 0 ), wx.GBSpan( 1, 3 ), wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_panel40 = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 40,10 ), wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        self.m_panel40.SetBackgroundColour( wx.SystemSettings.GetColour( wx.SYS_COLOUR_HIGHLIGHT ) )

        gbSizer1.Add( self.m_panel40, wx.GBPosition( 4, 0 ), wx.GBSpan( 1, 3 ), wx.ALL, 5 )


        self.SetSizer( gbSizer1 )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )


def main():
    app = wx.App(False)
    MainFrame = MyFrame1(None)
    MainFrame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When the above code is run it outputs:

[image]

## Edit

First. I haven't used the GridBagSizer before, so I apologize if the information that I give is misleading in any way. But wx.Size in this instance is part of a wx.Panel class, where as wx.GBSpan is part of a wx.GridBagSizer class. As such you might be able to expand the panel to fit the span, but I am not sure how to do this at the moment.

- http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.GBSpan-class.html
- http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Panel-class.html

It would appear that wx.GBSpan() defaults to 1 row cell and 1 column cell.

So, wx.GBSpan(rowspan=1,colspan=1) is the same as wx.GBSpan(1, 1).

And if you take a look at Robin Dunn's answer from the mailing lists archive...

http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/Problem-with-GridBagSizer-and-span-td2359250.html

```
> Hi all 
> 
> I understand what the 'span' argument to wx.GridBagSizer.Add() means, but it 
> is not behaving as I would expect. 
> 
> Assume I have two columns in my GBS, one with a width of 20 and one with a 
> width of 30. 
> 
> If I add a row containing an element with a width of 40, spanning both 
> columns, I expected that the existing sizes and positions would not change, 
> as there is ample room to fit the new row into the available width. 
> 
> In practice, the overall width is increased, and ugly spaces start to 
> appear.
... [show rest of quote]

IIRC when an item spans columns then its width is divided evenly across 
all the columns.  In other words, for an item that is 100 pixels wide 
that is spanned across 5 columns, then each column takes 'ownership' of 
20 pixels for that item.  So even if everything else in that column is 
only 10 pixels wide, the sizer is still going to assume that the col 
needs 20 pixels because of that column's share of the spanning item.
```

So for example with your Code:

```
self.m_panel29 = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 10,10 ), wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
self.m_panel29.SetBackgroundColour( wx.SystemSettings.GetColour( wx.SYS_COLOUR_INFOBK ) )
gbSizer1.Add( self.m_panel29, wx.GBPosition( 0, 6 ), wx.GBSpan( 1, 3 ), wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )
```

wx.GBSpan(rowspan=1, colspan=3) and wx.Size( 10, 10 ) width = 10 and height = 10.

Also worth taking a look at in regards to Size and expanding panels:

- [Getting a WxPython panel item to expand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104323/getting-a-wxpython-panel-item-to-expand)
- http://wiki.wxpython.org/wxGridBagSizer

Comment: Thanks for help. This is what I was looking for. Could you tell me how is the size and the span corelated ? I see that m_panel40 has wx.Size( 40,10 ) and wx.GBSpan( 5, 6 ), the smaller one - m_panel25 has wx.Size( 40,10 ) and wx.GBSpan( 1, 3 ) - the span make the difference, so why we need to specify size ?

Comment: Also, are there any chance to make only the big black panel growable ?
When I add growable col or row it also affect the smaller panels.

Comment: @AdrianBaran I updated by answer. Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your explanations helped me to understand GridBagSizer much better! :)
Now I am trying to make the biggest black panel growable. I used  AddGrowableRow(4) - this helped me to make the panel change dynamically its hight, but when I used AddGrowableCol(6) - it doesn't make any difference. Do you know what could cause that effect ?